# Is there a way to alert when a price is x% or $x away from a series?

Tags: pine-script

Goal: Have the ability to add an alert, or pop up a shape/text on screen, when a price approaches a configurable % or $ amount away from a series, say a 200MA. Basically setting up a dynamic channel around a series.

Is there a way to do this within Pine Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use `label.new()` or `alert()` functions.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")


ma = ema(close, 200)
plot(ma)

p = input(100, title="%", step=0.1) / 100 


if close*p > ma
    alert("Close price" + tostring(close) + "> than" + tostring(ma) + "on" + tostring(p) + "%")
    // label.new(bar_index, high, text = "Close price" + tostring(close) + "> than" + tostring(ma) + "on" + tostring(p) + "%")
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/